# Variance of point estimate for Least Squares

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, least-squares

I am trying to do a practice problem but am quite stuck, the question is as follows:

[image]

Where $\hat{\beta}_1$ is the coefficient for the the regressors. I figured that by the asymptotic normality property of LS estimates, then the $t_{\alpha / 2} = 1.96$. Hence, I think the confidence interval should be

$$\theta \in \bigg[ \hat{\theta} - 1.96\hat{se}(\hat{\theta}) ,\hat{\theta} + 1.96\hat{se}(\hat{\theta}) \bigg]$$

However I am unsure about the $\hat{se}(\hat{\theta})$ and how to express it in terms of the variance for LS estimator.

I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22delta+method%22 for one method (which likely is what this question is intended to evaluate).